# Применение форматирования к динамически-созданным элементам jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, javascript

Здравтсвуйте!

У меня есть страница

```
<div data-role="page">...</div>
```

И перед тем, как ее показать, я добавляю в нее динамический контент, а именно много `collapsible`

и после этого вызываю

```
.trigger( "create" );
```

для применения форматирования к динамически-созданному контенту.
    Все бы было хорошо, но в виду количестав этого самого контента его создание посредством

```
.trigger( "create" );
```

занимает ооооочень много времени(на мобильном устройстве, порядка 20-30 сек.)

Есть ли какая-либо альтернатива вызову .trigger( "create" );?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел такое вот рещение:
для каждого из нужных мне элементов(`data-role="button"`,`data-role="collapsible"`,`data-role="collapsible-set"`...) существуют функции, которые добавляют JQuery стили для этих элементов.
после добавления элемента, на пример `<div data-role="button"/>` я вызываю функцию `.button()` для созданного элемента.